# Specifying the size of a HashMap in Scala

Tags: scala, hashmap

I'm using Scala's mutable HashMap to incrementally add up to millions of key-value pairs. The resizing of these HashMaps is now the slowest part of my program. How can I tell Scala to create a very large HashMap from the start so that it (almost) never needs to be resized?

I would appreciate also any ideas that propose another Scala/Java collection that would suit my needs. Adding a new key-value pair and retrieving a value given a key should both be doable in approximately constant time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One of possible way:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.{HashTable, DefaultEntry}

trait BigHashTable[A, B] extends HashTable[A, DefaultEntry[A, B]] {
  override def initialSize: Int = 1024 // 16 - by default
}

val x = new HashMap[Int, String] with BigHashTable[Int, String]
```

another one:

```
class MyHashMap[A, B](initSize : Int) extends HashMap[A, B] {
  override def initialSize: Int = initSize // 16 - by default
}

val x = new MyHashMap[Int, String](1024)
```

Comment: Thanks! The second solution seems nicer to me. Is there any reason to prefer the first solution instead of the second?

Comment: Why not use `java.util.HashMap` directly without beating around the bush?

Answer (score 3):

[scala.collection.mutable.OpenHashMap](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/mutable/OpenHashMap.html) supports `initialSize`

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.HashMap` has a constructor that lets you specify an initial size. Unlike Yuriy's answer, there's no reason to write code that you don't need to.

jifeng.yin's answer is also acceptable, although since `OpenHashMap` uses an unspecified form of [Open Addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_addressing), you should benchmark for your use case and see how the change from chaining to open addressing matters, if it all.